# Are all ways to attain moksha pair wise compatible at implementation level?

Tags: scripture, moksha

It is true that all valid ways to attain moksha converges at the end. It means that they have same end result namely moksha. But the inner details (or) tasks to perform can be totally different for each valid way.

While practicing a particular way, is it possible to practice any other way in parallel and attaining the result? My question is intended for normal humans i.e., not for avatars.

Suppose there are 3 different ways to attain moksha: Bhakthi, Gnana, Karma. Are all the possible pairs compatible to perform in parallel?

I mean, is it possible for a person to perform the following pairs simultaneously: (Bhakthi, Gnana), (Gnana, Karma), (Bhakthi, Karma), (Bhakthi, Gnana, Karma) and then attaining moksha? It is possible only if there are no contradictions among them at implementation level. If no, what are the compatible pairs?

**Note**: Answers should be from scriptures and not from the opinions or from the books by historians, archeologists, modern experts, etc., (which this site is not intended for).

Comment: The hierarchy mentioned by one acharya is this : Karma -> Bhakti1 -> Jnana -> Bhakti2. of course you can have a bit of all 3 at each stage, but predominantly higher is shown.

Comment: @ram So, it mean, it may be infeasible to preform in parallel.

Comment: you can have a bit of all 3 at each stage, but in first stage karma should be higher than others. similarly for other 2 stages. The final stage is not an action to be done by you, it is just the result/fruit of below 3.